# cross-national and cross-cultural academic collaboration

Tags: authorship

Are there online avenue(s) for would-be cross-national and cross-cultural academic researcher to meet? There are times where one would want to broaden the scope of one's research.

Comment: Could you add some more detail? As it stands, the question is quite unclear: what do you mean by "meet online"? To do what? Who is a "cross-national and cross-cultural researcher"? Or do you mean "for researchers of different nations and cultures to meet"?

Comment: What I meant was that is there an online platform whereby academic researchers from different nationals or culture could meet to co-author a paper they both have similar interest on. I might be writing on private tutoring in Nigeria and I would want to  have another quantitative view on the said subject from another researcher in Saudi Arabia. If I do not have the opportunity to attend  international conference where I could interact with such researcher, is there any online platform available for cross-national researchers to interact on the same theme of research?

Comment: 1. What does culture have to do with all this? 2. Can't you simply send them an e-mail, or Skype with them, if you already know the person you want to work with?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there is such a platform.  It would be a good idea, but a lot of work to create one.

If one does not exist, I suggest you

- make a website where you post about your own work, and comments about others' work.  My partner is a physicist and made a primitive website. Believe it or not, strangers find this website and make contact to initiate collaborations.
- look on Google Scholar for articles that interest you.  Write to the authors of the articles that really intrigue you.  I have done that.  Rarely, there's no answer.  Sometimes, there's a one-line email and an attached article that is exactly what I was hoping to find.  Sometimes, there is an invitation to collaborate on a specific project!